# Firebase - myFirebase.child().once() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, firebase

I am using Firebase to create a web app. I can set values in my Firebase fine, but if I try to read them, I get undefined. Here is my code:

```
            var str = document.URL;
            var padId = str.slice(55, 65);
            alert(padId);
            var myFirebase = new Firebase("https://collab-coding-privacy.firebaseio.com/" + padId);

            var isPrivate;
            var owner = "";
            var pemial = "";

            myFirebase.child("private").on('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.val() != undefined) {
                    isPrivate = true;
                }
            });
            alert(isPrivate);

            myFirebase.child("pemial").on('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.val() != null) {
                    pemail = snapshot.val();
                }
            });
            alert(pemail);


            myFirebase.child("owner").on('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.val() != null) {
                    owner = snapshot.val();
                }
            });
            alert(owner);
```

When I load the page it first alerts the padId, which I check and exists in my firebase. Then it alerts pemail, owner, and isPrivate, which are all undefined.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing an asynchronous operation and then immediately trying to read the return value in a synchronous scope. The value is undefined because the callback to on('value') has not yet been invoked. Move the alerts inside of the callbacks and you will see the actual values.

Comment: How can we export data from callback function?